# Runtime Error 1004 paste method of worksheet class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following subroutine. I am new to VBA so I imagine it is inefficient and clunky. In essence I am trying to call another subroutine (UpdateBlocksSingle) that does something and then I would like to take a screenshot of the results, paste it into a new spreadhseet called "Screenshots" and then export the results to a pdf. All of this is done in a loop so I generate a lot of screenshots (and a lot of pages in the pdf). I also begin the process of taking a screenshot out of the loop.

The piece that continues to generate the 1004 error is:

```
CopyRangeSingle.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
Screen.Paste Destination:=PasteRange.Offset(56 * i, 1)
Sheets("Screenshots").Rows(56 * i).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
```

The error will occur randomly i.e. sometimes after 10 iterations through the loop other times after 1 or 2. When I change the appearance type from xlScreen to xlPrinter I no longer get the error. Andy advice on how to change the code so that I can successfully loop through and take screenshots while keeping the resolution of xlScreen would be much appreciated.

```
Sub LoopWaterProviders()

'If a former Screenshot tab exits delete it
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Screenshots" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("Screenshots").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next

Call CreateSheet

Sheets("BlockChart").Select

Dim WaterProviders As Long
Dim OpenPDF As Boolean
Dim ProviderType As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim OutSht As Worksheet
Dim CopyRangeSingle As Range
Dim CopyRangeBlock As Range
Dim PasteRange As Range
Dim Block As Worksheet
Dim Screen As Worksheet

j = 1
ProviderType = Sheets("Multiple Block Charts").Range("A1").Value
OpenPDF = Sheets("Multiple Block Charts").Range("A2").Value
Set Screen = Sheets("Screenshots")
Set Block = Sheets("BlockChart")
Set CopyRangeSingle = Block.Range("S1:AJ50")
Set CopyRangeBlock = Block.Range("A1:P43")
Set PasteRange = Screen.Cells(1, 1)

If ProviderType = 1 Then
WaterProviders = Sheets("Calculations_Single").Range("C11").Value
ElseIf ProviderType = 2 Then
WaterProviders = Sheets("Multiple Block Charts").Range("F13").Value
ElseIf ProviderType = 3 Then
WaterProviders = Sheets("Multiple Block Charts").Range("H15").Value
ElseIf ProviderType = 4 Then
WaterProviders = Sheets("Multiple Block Charts").Range("K61").Value
Else: WaterProviders = Sheets("Calculations_Single").Range("C11").Value
End If

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
CopyRangeBlock.CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture
Screen.Paste Destination:=PasteRange
Sheets("Screenshots").Rows(56).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Worksheets("BlockChart").Select

For i = 1 To WaterProviders

    If ProviderType = 1 Then
    Sheets("Calculations_Single").Range("C12").Value = i
    ElseIf ProviderType = 2 Then
    Sheets("Calculations_Single").Range("C12").Value = Sheets("Multiple Block Charts").Cells(i + 1, 6)
    ElseIf ProviderType = 3 Then
    Sheets("Calculations_Single").Range("C12").Value = Sheets("Multiple Block Charts").Cells(i + 1, 9)
    ElseIf ProviderType = 4 Then
    Sheets("Calculations_Single").Range("C12").Value = Sheets("Multiple Block Charts").Cells(i + 1, 12)

    Else: Sheets("Calculations_Single").Range("C12").Value = i
    End If

    Call UpdateBlocksSingle

    CopyRangeSingle.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    Screen.Paste Destination:=PasteRange.Offset(56 * i, 1)
    Sheets("Screenshots").Rows(56 * i).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

    Next i

    Sheets("Screenshots").Range("A:S").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="G:\P_and_R\DATA_TOOLS\Shortage Impacts\Single_Year_BLOCK_CHART\Provider_and_CAP_Supply_Block_AC_ver1.X_Output\ProviderOutputCharts", _
    OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDF, _
    Quality:=xlQualityHighest, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=WaterProviders + 1


MsgBox "Export complete and PDF saved to 'G:\P_and_R\DATA_TOOLS\Shortage Impacts\Single_Year_BLOCK_CHART\Provider_and_CAP_Supply_Block_AC_ver1.X_Output' "
Sheets("BlockChart").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a line `DoEvents` after `CopyRangeSingle.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture`. Now check

Comment: Wow. That seems to have solved the issue. Very Simple.

Could you provide some insight into why this was happening and how the solution solves the issue?

Comment: When you are executing copy paste in a loop (or otherwise) you need to give excel time to copy and place things in clipboard. Your paste line was executing before the item was getting copied. All we did was gave excel some time...

Comment: I spoke a little too soon. Now the loop executes for significantly more iterations (~30)  but still gives me the "Run-time error '1004' CopyPicture method of Range class failed" at later iterations. I've added the line 'Application.Wait (Now + 0.00003) to give it more time to paste and see if this helps...

Comment: This is a different error :)  What is the address of the range when you get the copy error?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the range address is S1:AJ50. The error happens at the 'CopyRangeSingle.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture' line. Since adding the Application.Wait line the error has stopped but it doesn't sound like this is an actual fix??